# Clapper, changing configuration bits in C

Tags: c, ide, pic, microprocessors, mplab

Hope I can ask my question on here.
I have build a clapper from this site http://embedded-lab.com/blog/?p=6439 
He used a PIC12F683 but I hade a PIC16F628 home so I used it. 
I wonder if someone could help med with the c code? And correct me if I have put the wires to the right pins.
I have tried to read the datasheets for both the PICs, on the pins and how to change the configuration bits by but I have a hard time to understand it fully.

I have wired the pins like this from the site.

T1 and R10K is connected to RA2,
GND is connected to Vss,
+5V is connected to Vdd,
LED and R330 is connected to RB6.

Here is the code with my changes.

```
//sbit Output_LED at GP5_bit; on the original code
#define Output_LED PORTD.F3;

//sbit led_led at PORTc.c2;
unsigned short i, TIME_UP;

 void interrupt(void){
 if(PIR1.TMR1IF){
   i ++;
   if(i == 3) TIME_UP = 1; // Time Up in 1.5 sec 
   PIR1.TMR1IF = 0;
  } 
}

void main() {
  TRISIO = 0b00000011 ;
  //ANSEL = 0x00; on the original code
  INTCON = 0b11000000 ; // Enable GIE and PEIE for Timer1 overflow interrpt
  PIE1 = 0b00000001 ; // Enable TMR1IE

  // Configure Comparator module
  // CIN- pin is configured as analog,
  // CIN+ pin is configured as I/O,
  // COUT pin is configured as I/O,
  // Comparator output available internally,
  // CVREF is non-inverting input 
  // CINV is set to 1

  COMCON = 0b00010100; 
  VRCON = 0b10100011; // Vref is set to VDD/8
  Output_LED = 0;
  do{ TMR1H = 0x00;
     TMR1L = 0x00;
     TIME_UP = 0;
     i = 0;
     T1CON = 0b00110000; // Configure Timer 1 
     if(CMCON0.COUT){ // First clap detected
       Delay_ms(100);
       T1CON.TMR1ON = 1; // Start Timer1
       while(!COMCON.COUT && !TIME_UP); // Wait until second clap is 
       T1CON.TMR1ON = 0; // detected or Timer1 overflows
       if(COMCON.COUT && !TIME_UP) Output_LED =  ~Output_LED; 
       Delay_ms(100); 
     } 
  }   while(1);
}




//- See more at: http://embedded-lab.com/blog/?p=6439#sthash.YHvZk7SY.dpuf
```

The error message I get when I build is:

```
Clean: Deleting intermediary and output files.
Clean: Done.
Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\PK2proj\Cc5x\CC5X.EXE" clapper.c -CC -fINHX8M -p16F628 -a -L -Q -V -FM
CC5X Version 3.3A, Copyright (c) B Knudsen Data, Norway 1992-2007
 --> FREE edition, 8-16 bit int, 24 bit float, 1k code, reduced optim.
clapper.c:

 void first_interrupt( void){
  if(PIR1.TMR2IF){
               ^------
Error[1] C:\Program Files (x86)\PK2proj\Work\clapper.c 31 : Syntax error
 (The expression must be corrected. The marker ^------ shows
 the approximate position where CC5X gives up. The documentation
 should be checked if the cause is not obvious)

Error options: -ew: no warning details  -ed: no error details  -eL: list details
BUILD FAILED: Wed Jan 15 01:36:50 2014
```

(I'm using MPLAB IDE 8.92, PICkit 3, B Knudsen Data CC5X)

I would be realy thankfull if someone could help me :)

Comment: We're going to need more information.  What exactly fails?  Is the output always on, always off? Have you been able to use a debugger on the code and determine if it detects the claps for instance?  Also improving the indentation and line breaks (like in the original code) would make it much easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have fixed the code and added my error message. I can't debugg it (I thnink because the code is to wrong).
I'm new with programing and tought it would be fun and educational with this project :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you too much.  The PIC code I've seen is in assembly, and this is a compiler problem.  It looks just like the example on the line where it fails, but he uses the MikroC Pro compiler, whereas you're using Knudsen Data compiler.  That might be the difference. Poke around Knudsen's website, see what you can find on interrupts.  BTW, I hope you're familiar with electronics because learning both hardware and software together can be tough.  If you want to only learn software, some C# examples with VS Express might be an option.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I have looked on Knudsen's homepage but could not found anything..
I went a electronic cours and liked it very much, but the code is more difficult for me :/
I will look on some exemples on C :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to use `PIR1bits.TMR2IF` instead of `PIR1.TMR2IF`.

I'm unfamiliar with the Knudsen complier. If this doesn't work, let me know here and I'll include other methods.